# is this a function declaration?

Tags: c++, opencv, opencascade

Often I see this type of declaration+implementation in C++ when I read some codes from OpenCV or OpenCascade

```
TEST(Shape_SCD, regression)
{
    const int NSN_val=5;//10;//20; //number of shapes per class
    const int NP_val=120; //number of points simplifying the contour
    const float CURRENT_MAX_ACCUR_val=95; //99% and 100% reached in several tests, 95 is fixed as minimum boundary
    ShapeBaseTest<float, computeShapeDistance_Chi> test(NSN_val, NP_val, CURRENT_MAX_ACCUR_val);
    test.safe_run();
}
```

This can turn out to be a silly question, isn't it? since I don't get what type of declaration this is. It does look like a function but there is no return type. If it is a constructor, why isn't there any type of the variables in argument list?

Thanks

Comment: or I might think this is a macro defined elsewhere in the library? this should be right :D

Comment: It looks like a test definition using the google test framework (https://github.com/google/googletest)

Comment: @PaulRooney Technically that doesn't answer his question. They're macros.

Comment: Since this is opencv we are talking about, https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/ts/include/opencv2/ts/ts_ext.hpp

Comment: Thanks @PaulRooney! you open me up to the concept of test framework. @T.C. ok! so OpenCV has its test framework of its own. Both are interesting for me to know more!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TEST` is a macro. After the macro is expanded, this will be a normal function definition (with a return type). You should be able to see this if you look up the definition of the macro.